# Android Studio Tutorial Error

Tags: java, android, xml

I've recently been following the Android Studio tutorial 
(or tutoriel, for those undertale fans).

I've reached the 'Starting Another Activity' stage ([link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)).
Here I ran into a bit of trouble.
The tutorial told me to insert 'android:id=@+id/content"> in the 'content_display_message.xml' file.

I've done so, but the AS said that it was unexpected?

Then after I ignored this error, I ran into a problem. When I added

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
```

into the DisplayMessageActivity.java file, an error came up explaining that 'content' was undefined.
 I am pretty sure I did what I was tasked to do, and I am not sure what has caused such an error.

My full code is here:

DisplayMessageActivity.java:

```
package com.example.denny.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null)
                        .show();
            }
        });
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
        layout.addView(textView);
    }
}
```

content_display_message.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.denny.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_display_message">
    android:id="@+id/content">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invalid xml, Change your xml to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.denny.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_display_message" // Changed this line
    android:id="@+id/content">
</RelativeLayout>
```